# is it possible to convert the code using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to convert the display the content of the list such that only three elements print in each line, and able to write the below code using if/else, which is working as expected..

```
lst = ["s1","s2","s3","s4","s5","s6","s7","s8"]

cnt=0
var4=""

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if (cnt%3) == 0:
        var4 = var4 + "\n" + lst[i]
    else:
        var4 = var4 + ", " + lst[i]
    cnt +=1 
    
print(var4)
```

Output:

```
s1, s2, s3
s4, s5, s6
s7, s8
```

Trying to find if the same result can be achieved using List Comprehension or some other efficient possible way.

thanks..!!

Comment: print(("".join(["{0} {1}".format(element, "\n") if (index+1) % 3 == 0 else "{0}, ".format(element) for index, element in enumerate(lst)])))

Comment: `print(''.join(v + (', ' if i%3 else '\n') for i,v in enumerate(["s1","s2","s3","s4","s5","s6","s7","s8"], start=1)).rstrip(', '))` but that's not an improvement over normal style.

Comment: Who closed this? This is not even related to splitting the list into equally sized chunks. Not as long as what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here's a solution using list comprehension with `join`.

```
lst = ["s1","s2","s3","s4","s5","s6","s7","s8"]

block_size = 3

lines = [", ".join(lst[i:min(len(lst), i + block_size)]) for i in range(0, len(lst) + block_size, block_size)]

print("\n".join(lines))
```

Comment: It's not list comprehension